How to change node-soap timestamp duration and prefix?
I am trying to consume a SOAP service using node-soap using WSSecurityCert. The service requires me to set the timestamp in such a way that the SOAP request has a validity of 5 minutes and wsu prefix. The node-soap library has 10 minutes of validity "hard-coded", with no obvious way to override it. I don't know how or if I can just modify the timestamp before it is sent, because the WSSecurityCert signature might be invalidated.
My code:
const client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);

const securityOptions = {
  hasTimeStamp: true,
}

const wsSecurity = new soap.WSSecurityCert(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_CERT, '', securityOptions);

client.setSecurity(wsSecurity);

const result = await client.method(args);

The generated timestamp looks like this:
<Timestamp
  xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  Id="_1">
  <Created>2024-05-08T13:20:09Z</Created>
  <Expires>2024-05-08T13:30:09Z</Expires>
</Timestamp>

I need to make the timestamp look something like this:
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-7C14BF4AA3E26845E015637928928701">
  <wsu:Created>2024-05-08T13:20:09Z</wsu:Created>
  <wsu:Expires>2024-05-08T13:25:09Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>

I tried to add created and expires among other things to securityOptions, to no avail.
Is it possible to achieve this with the node-soap library without forking it?

The issue I'm having could benefit from this answer. My issue is that the timestamp gets Id="_1" but adding a signing reference to anything else also gives it Id="_1" so there are TWO elements with the same ID. I know in postProcess you can do any manipulation you want, but not sure if that's a viable answer here, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78449925/990642.

soap doesn't offer any way to customize the timestamp header, see the hardcoded lines: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/src/security/WSSecurityCert.ts#L124.
But you can disable the library's timestamp generation and add your own.
Step 1: Disable hasTimestamp, add signing reference
const options: IWSSecurityCertOptions = {
  hasTimeStamp: false,
  additionalReferences: [
    'wsu:Timestamp',
    'wsa:To',
  ],
  signerOptions: {
    prefix: 'ds',
    attrs: { Id: 'Signature' },
    existingPrefixes: {
      wsse11: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd',
    },
  },
};
const wsSecurity = new WSSecurityCert(privateKey, publicKey, password, options);
soapClient.setSecurity(wsSecurity);

Step 2: Add your own timestamp
const expiry = '2100-05-08T00:00:00Z'; // TODO: compute this
const id = 'TS-7C14BF4AA3E26845E015637928928701'; // TODO: compute this
soapClient.addSoapHeader((methodName, location, soapAction, args) => {
  return '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">' +
    `<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="${id}">` +
    `<wsu:Created>${new Date().toISOString()}</wsu:Created>` +
    `<wsu:Expires>${expiry}</wsu:Expires>` +
    '</wsu:Timestamp>' +
    '</wsse:Security>';
});

Note that toISOString() will have the timestamp with miliseconds, this wasn't an issue for the SOAP service I'm working with.
Notice that the security header is included in here. This works because there is logic within soap to adjust accordingly, see https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/src/security/WSSecurityCert.ts#L141.
Side note: I had to write my import statement like the following for the security classes, not sure if there's a better way:
import { IWSSecurityCertOptions, WSSecurityCert } from 'soap/lib/security/WSSecurityCert';

RESULT
Your SOAP security header will have:
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-7C14BF4AA3E26845E015637928928701">
    <wsu:Created>
        2024-05-10T17:23:56.937Z
    </wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>
        2100-05-08T00:00:00Z
    </wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>

And a signed reference like:
<ds:Reference URI="#TS-7C14BF4AA3E26845E015637928928701">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>
        GR__REDACTED__e24=
    </ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>


Thank you @josephdpurcell. This appears to have worked for me.
By the way, in your comment to my question you mentioned I know in postProcess you can do any manipulation you want. You reckon it would be possible to encrypt the SOAP request (xmlenc 1.1) in post process? Not asking how; that would warrant a separate question in itself, just if you think it would be possible?

@Octavian I suppose you COULD do that in the postProcess. In my meanderings around the Internet for node soap discussions and issues I don't recall seeing anything on xmlenc since I haven't had to solve for that, so I don't have a good suggestion. I can say that from what I see postProcess gets called last and would be a reasonable "seam" to introduce custom logic on the HTTP request body.

Not sure if I should edit my other answer, but there is a completely OTHER approach you could take:
Create your own WSSecurityCert class and modify the timestamp as you wish.
Step 1: Copy the class into your own WSSecurityCert
See https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/src/security/WSSecurityCert.ts for the latest, but make sure you switch to the tagged version of soap you're using.
Step 2: Modify the class
Change Line 140 to be like:
if (this.hasTimeStamp) {
  timestampStr =
    `<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-${generateId()}">` +
    `<wsu:Created>${this.created}</wsu:Created>` +
    `<wsu:Expires>${this.expires}</wsu:Expires>` +
    `</wsu:Timestamp>`;
}

Step 3: Wire up your custom security class
Do exactly as you would normally:
// Where WSSecurityCert is an import of your own version of the class
const wsSecurity = new WSSecurityCert(/** params */);
soapClient.setSecurity(wsSecurity);

RESULT
Your SOAP security header will have:
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-43dfbc1c4e8046f7b0065acdee3a2ad1">
    <wsu:Created>
        2024-05-10T17:01:27Z
    </wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>
        2024-05-10T17:11:27Z
    </wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>

And a signed reference like:
<ds:Reference URI="#TS-43dfbc1c4e8046f7b0065acdee3a2ad1">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>
        gZe__REDACTED__8g=
    </ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>

